# Why do I get an TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list error when running my program?

Tags: python

When i run through my python code:

```
import time

print("\n\n\t\tWelcome to the Automated Troubleshooting Program\n\n")
time.sleep(1)
name = input("Before we begin, what is your name?\nName: ")

time.sleep(1)
option_end = False
while option_end == False:
option = input("Would you like to quit or carry on?\nChoice: ")
option = option.lower()
if option == 'carry on':
    option_end = True

    question_end = False
    while question_end == False:
        question = input("\nWhat is wrong with your device?\nProblem: ")
        question = question.lower()
        words = question.split()
        print("")

        searchfile = open("Mobile Troubleshooter Problems.txt", "r")

        for line in searchfile:

            if words in line:
                print (line)
                question_end = True
            searchfile.close()

            if words not in line:
                print("Invalid input.\nPlease try again.\n")
                time.sleep(1)
                question_end = False
            searchfile.close()

if option == 'quit':
    print("Shutting down in: 3")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("                                   2")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("                                   1")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\n\n\t\t\t\t...SHUTTING DOWN...")
    time.sleep(1)
    quit()
```

I get this error:

line 26, in 
    if words in line:
TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not list

(When going through the code type: your name, 'carry on', 'device screen')

Here is the data from the .txt notebook file:

```
screen: there is no display on the device screen - Solution: send to the supplier to get the screen fixed.
screen: the device screen is cracked - Solution: send to the supplier to get the screen fixed.
speakers: there is no sound on the device - Solution: send back to the supplier to get speakers fixed.
camera: the camera is not working - Solution: send back to the supplier to get the camera fixed.
software: the phone keeps on crashing / failing - Solution: send back to the supplier to get the software fixed.
```

Comment: `if words in line:` is checking if a list (`words`) is in a string (`line`). You need to reverse these: `if line in words:`

Comment: Why are you closing the file while you are looping over the lines?

Comment: Thanks guys I needed help on that question - even my teacher couldn't figure it out - you guys must be experts. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start you have an indentation error on your first while loop.

The problem is that you are trying to check if a list is in a string (doesn't work).

The split in line 19 changes the variable words to a list.

If you want to check if any of the words in question are in the line of search file you should try

```
if any(wd in line for wd in words):
```

Comment: Thanks I needed help on that question (as I have said to the other responses) - even my teacher couldn't figure it out - you must be an expert. Thank you